# R is only returning non-zero coefficient estimates when using the "poly" function to generate predictors. How do I get the zero values into a vector?

Tags: r

I'm using `regsubsets` from the `leaps` library to perform the best subset selection. I need to compare the coefficients it generates to the "true" coefficients I specified when simulating the data (by comparison, meaning, the difference between them squared, and the square root taken of the sum), for each number of predictors.

Since there are 16 different models that `regsubsets` generated, I use a loop to do this automatically. It would work except that when I extract the coefficients from the best model fit with x predictors, it only gives me the non-zero coefficients of the polynomial fit. This messes up the size of the `coefi` vector causing it to be smaller in size than the `truecoef` true coefficients vector.

If I could somehow force all coefficients to be spat out from the model, I wouldn't have an issue. But after looking extensively, I don't know how to do that.

Alternative ways of solving this problem would also be appreciated.

```
library(leaps)
regfit.train=regsubsets(y ~ poly(x,25, raw = TRUE), data=mydata[train,], nvmax=25)

truecoef = c(3,0,-7,4,-2,8,0,-5,0,2,0,4,5,6,3,2,2,0,3,1,1)

coef.errors = rep(NA, 16)
for (i in 1:16) {
    coefi = coef(regfit.train, id=i)
    coef.errors[i] = mean((truecoef-coefi)^2)
}
```

The equation I'm trying to estimate, where j is the coefficient and r refers to the best model containing "r" coefficients:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about using lapply and returning a list? that will tolerate different lengths.  Then you can convert the list to a data frame using the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it (with some help):

The loop indexes which coefficients are available and performs the subtraction, for those unavailable, it assumes they are zero.

```
truecoef = c(3,0,-7,4,-2,8,0,-5,0,2,0,4,5,6,3,2,2,0,3,1,1)


val.errors = rep(NA, 16)
x_cols = colnames(x, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "x.")

for (i in 1:16) {
    coefis = coef(regfit.train, id = i)
    val.errors[i] = sqrt(sum((truecoef[x_cols %in% names(coefis)] - 
    coefis[names(coefis) %in% x_cols])^2) + sum(truecoef[!(x_cols %in% names(coefis))])^2)
}
```